# Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message

Tags: php, api, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using "Create Dynamic Links with the REST API" and I used following code for this. This is using the google firebase dynamic links API.

```
$long_url = "https://etisalatone.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/reload/10&apn=com.omobio.etisalatone";

$api_url = 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=';

$data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //timeout in seconds

if ($type == 'POST') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}

$api_time_track = microtime();

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

The following error is produced as a result:

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a
>   message.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what could be causing the issue without any reference to the URL itself. Its specified in `$url` and from the tags it looks like you're using a shortened URL or are trying to shorten a URL. My only guess is that you're sending your request to the incorrect location

Comment: @Hive7 It works on postman

Comment: And I assume you have a valid API key and that the correct API key is attached in the key field?

Comment: @Hive7 API key is ok

Comment: What does `$data` look like after encoding?